# How to retrieve array inside array based on a value with firestore

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document structure called session which contains an array called seances in which there is an array called student.

I would like to retrieve all the documents where a given value is in the array students; for example if the value is Alice, and I have the following 3 documents :

**Doc 1**

```
{
      name: "doc1"
      seances: [
       {
        date: "02/01",
        students: ["Alice","John","Brahim"]
        }
                ]
    }
```

**Doc 2**

```
{
          name: "doc2"
          seances: [
            {
            date: "12/04",
            students: ["Alice","John","Brahim"]
            }
          ]
        }
```

**Doc 3**

```
{
      name: "doc3"
      seances: [
        {
       date: "21/03",
       students: ["Arysse","John","Brahim"]
        },
        {
        date: "22/05",
        students: ["Steward","John","Brahim"]
        }
              ]
            }
```

In this case, it should return Doc 1 and Doc 2 because it contains the value "Alice" inside the array Students which contains the array sessions despite other fields like date.

Is it possible to do that using only where clause with firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.  You can't query for the contents of arrays inside other object arrays.  In order to satisfy this query, you'll have to keep another field with the array you want to search, and use an [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) query on that field.